# I have a problem, send requests not work in FastApi+Gunicorn?

Tags: python-requests, fastapi, gunicorn

I use `gunicorn main:app -b 0.0.0.0:9700  -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --timeout 600` to deploy my app. It starts normally.

[image: 1]

But it's not working when i send request in '/test' route.

```
@app.get('/test')
def test():
    r = requests.get("https://google.com")
    return {'code': 0, 'msg: '123'}
```

I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

[image: 3]

I tried remove `requests.get('http://example.com')`. It's working.

```
@app.get('/test')
    def test():
        # r = requests.get("https://google.com")
        return {'code': 0, 'msg: '123'}
```

[image: 5]

my code:

```
import requests
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def index():
    return 'hello'

@app.get('/test')
def test():
    r = requests.get("https://google.com")
    return {'code': 0, 'msg': '123'}
```

The code works fine in Uvicorn but not in Gunicorn.

I don't know why. It's working in Ubuntu 20, but not in macOS ? -.-

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. Maybe try adding `--access-logfile FILE` and have a look at the logs first

Comment: I added it, there is no useful information in the accesslog

Comment: Are the request responding with a 200 HTTP Code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is nothing in accesslog file ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following in order to see the error in your requests call:

```
@app.get("/test")
def test():
    try:
        r = requests.get("http://example.com")
    except Exception as e:
        return e.__str__()
    return JSONResponse({"code": 1})
```

**Example error response**

```
"HTTPConnectionPool(host='examasple.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000014CD5BEAA30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))"
```